# Iniciar sesión en PHP mediante llamada AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, webix

Estoy intentando establecer el id de sesión, generado en PHP, mediante una llamada AJAX.

La idea es:

1. Desde Javascript, envio mediante `POST` los datos de *login*.
2. Un *script* PHP los procesa y, si son correctos, devuelve un `JSON` con el identificador de sesión.
3. Desde Javascript, recojo el identificador de sesión y lo asigno a la *cookie* `PHPSESSID`.

El código PHP es muy simple:

```
// login.php
<?php

session_start( );

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {
  $_SESSION['USER'] = 'Sesion iniciada.';
  echo json_encode( [ 'result' => session_id( ) ] );
} else {
  header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );

  foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $val )
    echo $key, ': ', $val, "\n";

  echo $_SESSION['USER'] ?? 'Sesion NO iniciada';
}
```

El `HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var promise = webix.ajax( ).post( 'login.php' );

promise.then( function( data ) {
  webix.storage.cookie.put( 'PHPSESSID', data.json( ).result );
  console.log( webix.storage.cookie.get( 'PHPSESSID' );
  debugger; // Si lo quito, se limpia la consola.
  location = 'login.php';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Al abrir en el navegador el `HTML`, con la instrucción `debugger` puesta (si la elimino, al cambiar de página, se limpia la consola), obtengo:

> `09qmq92b0flaol57m4f06ipfd6`

**Aparentemente**, el establecer la *cookie* **funciona** correctamente.

Sin embargo, la salida final, al llamar al código `PHP` mediante `GET`, muestra lo siguiente:

> `PHPSESSID:`
>   `Sessón NO iniciada.`

Aparentemente, el identificador de sesión se envía **vacío**, por lo que la sesión **no** se restaura.

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: Se habían *traspuesto* un par de cosas en el código, como acertadamente indica @OscarGarcia. Corregido. Pasa por preguntar a la vez que modifico el código, probando. El fallo persiste después de la edición.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu programa no funcionó a la primera tras arreglar algunos problemas en el código que publicaste. La sesión se generaba, los archivos de sesión se generaban con información, pero el `login.php` se negaba a mostrar información de sesión.

Cuando empecé a mirar el tráfico de red, las cookies, almacenamiento de cookies, etc me di cuenta que hacía dos cookies, la primera era la que salía en la consola de depuración y otra adicional con la ruta de pruebas que contenía comillas.

Decidí quitar la parte en la que se creaba una cookie con el resultado en JSON y... voila... el problema era que para la ruta del script PHP se cambiaba el valor de la cookie y, por lo tanto, se perdía lo creado anteriormente.

Una vez resuelto el problema me puse a investigar el origen de esa conversión en la cookie al hacer [webix.storage.cookie.put()](https://docs.webix.com/api__storage.cookie_put.html). El problema radica en que el parámetro esperado es un objeto, ya que webix parece almacenar los datos en JSON en dicha cookie (una cadena de caracteres codificada en JSON es simplemente dicha cadena entrecomillada), por lo que una solución al problema (sin eliminar el código) podría ser guardar los datos de webix en una cookie diferente (ver nuevo código).

El código final usado para reproducir tu problema ha sido:

**inicio.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.webix.com/edge/webix_debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var promise = webix.ajax(  ).post( 'login.php' );

promise.then( function( data ) {
  webix.storage.cookie.put( 'webix', {
    'PHPSESSID': data.json().result
  });
  console.log( webix.storage.cookie.get( 'webix' ) );
  //debugger; // Si lo quito, se limpia la consola.
  location = 'login.php';
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start( );

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {
  $_SESSION['USER'] = 'Sesion iniciada.';
  echo json_encode( [ 'result' => session_id( ) ] );
} else {
  header( 'Content-Type', 'text/plain' );

  foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $val ) {
    echo '<p>', htmlspecialchars($key . ': ' . $val ), "</p>\n";
}

  echo isset($_SESSION['USER']) ? 'Sesión iniciada' : 'Sesión NO iniciada';
}
```

Ahora la consola de depuración de javascript arroja este dato: `Object {PHPSESSID: "t4ko0seim5inlgvg0p1crcn0d3"}` y la cookie creada con dicha información codificada en JSON se llama `webix`.

[Dejo la revisión inicial aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/68834/3).

Comment: Llevas razón. Tal y como escribía la pregunta, estaba haciendo pruebas y modificando el código, y al final quedó algo *traspuesto*; el código **exacto** es el que tú indicas, pero la *funcionalidad* persiste; manda la *cookie* vacía. Edito la pregunta con tus correcciones.

Comment: Pero el `??` no me da error. `php -l login.php` no detecta errores. PHP --version `PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.10.4 (cli)`.

Comment: Ya está, perdona, empecé a pegar código y le di a enviar antes de hacer los cambios :( he ido editando conforme redactaba. PD: Si quieres que no se pierda el log de la consola de depuración o el de red marca la opción "Perserve log".

Comment: He limpiado la respuesta dejando únicamente lo relevante para resolver el problema.

Comment: He agregado una sugerencia de cambio en tu código para que veas el funcionamiento del almacenamiento de datos en una cookie que usa webix. PD: No he usado nunca webix, ha sido mi primer contacto con ese framework, por eso desconocía ese comportamiento.

Comment: ¿ Para que usará `webix.storage.cookie.put( )` ese primer argumento ? Con pasarle un solo argumento, de tipo `object`, habría suficiente, ¿ no ? Si al final lo que mande mediante *cookie*s es el contenido de ese objeto :-/

Comment: Las cookies creadas cn esa función puedes ser obtenidas y analizadas por el PHP y acceder a la información contenida en ella con `json_decode`, pero es una mala práctica almacenar información compartida y variable entre el cliente y el servidor en cookies. Piensa que toda esa información navega entre el cliente y el servidor EN CADA petición HTTP, incluso para descargar una simple imagen u hoja de estilos. Conforme aumente el tamaño de los datos aumenta el tráfico de red también y si el transporte es HTTP en vez de HTTPS estás exponiendo datos en texto claro en cada petición, aunque no se usen

Comment: Ahh, se me olvidaba. Ese primer parámetro es el nombre de la cookie. La ventaja de usar `webix` es que no tienes que [analizar el contenido de `document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) para hacer un análisis de su contenido para modificarlo.

Comment: Esto es para un *login*, pero en lugar de un formulario PHP, pues que PHP la genere igual, pero me la envie por AJAX y yo la establezco en mi código. Lo hago así para poder mostrar mensajes de `Login incorrecto` sin cambiar de página. Y algo se me escapa, porque el ejemplo funciona, pero al integrarlo en el código real, sigue fallando. Aún haré otro pregunta y todo :-/

Comment: Pero en un sistema de login entregas por POST los datos de usuario y contraseña al servidor y devuelves una de dos, o un token (en cuyo caso no necesitas `session_start` en PHP ni las variables $_SESSION, todo puede estar en la cookie y/o una base de datos con la información relacionada con el token) junto con un flag (true|false) de resultado más un mensaje en caso de error, o bien esa misma información sin el token, en ese caso las variables $_SESSION sólo estarán disponibles en el servidor, no en el cliente.

Comment: Si se usa `session_start( )`, PHP genera una *cookie* llamada `PHPSESSID` con un identificador de sesión, que es en realidad el nombre de un archivo, en el que se guardan los datos de `$_SESSION[]`. Yo quiero **generar la cookie** (con `sessión_start( )`), y enviar su **valor** por AJAX, no los datos de `$_SESSION[]`. Para que puede seguir usando `session_start( )` en PHP, pero sin verme forzado a hacer un <form ... >. Así no hay redirección, salvo cuando yo quiera. Y, al tener puesta una `PHPSESSID`, PHP sigue funcionando bien. Esa es **la teoría**; la práctica ... no va :-(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58497/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-trauma).